# equivalence relation and $R|_{Y}$ relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let $X,Y$ be sets so $Y\subseteq X$.

Let $R$ be equivalence relation of $X$. lets define $R|_{Y}$ to be a realtion on $Y$ so $R|_{Y}=(Y\times Y)\cap R$.

Is $R|_{B}$ reflexive? symmetric? transitive?

what I tried:

let $x\in X$. Since $R$ is reflexive $(x,x)\in R$ and the $(x,x)\in R|_{Y}$ so $R|_{Y}$ is reflexive.

let $x,y\in X$. since $R$ is symmetric - if $(x,y)\in R$ so $(y,x)\in R$ and then if $(x,y)\in R|_{Y}$ so $(y,x)\in R|_{Y}$ so $R|_{Y}$ is symmetric.

let $x,y,z\in X$. since $R$ is transitive - if $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$ so $(x,z)\in R$ and then if $(x,y)\in R|_{Y}$ and $(y,z)\in R|_{Y}$ so $(x,z)\in R|_{Y}$ so $R|_{Y}$ is transitive.

**edit**: let $(y,y)\in Y\times Y$ so $(y,y)\in X\times X$ and since $R$ is reflexive on $X$, $\forall x\in X, xRx$ so $(y,y)\in R|_{Y}$.

Is it correct? what now?

Comment: You are trying to prove that $R \mid_Y$ is an equivalence relation. Therefore, you should take $y \in Y$ and work with that. More precisely, for reflexivity, you should answer the question "Is $(y,y) \in R \mid_Y$ true"? You didn't show that. Do you see the issue I'm talking about?

Comment: @stressed-out But what is the connection between $Y$ and $R$? How I use that $R$ is equivalence relation to prove it about $Y$?

Comment: $Y$ is a subset of $X$. Therefore, if something is true for every pair of elements in $X \times X$, it must be true for every pair of elements in $Y \times Y$ too. $R \mid_Y$ is simply the restriction of the relation on $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: Yup. It looks fine to me. :) In other words, $y \in Y \implies y \in X \implies (y,y)\in R \implies (y,y) \in R \cap (Y\times Y) \implies (y,y) \in R\mid_Y$. You can follow the same logic for the other parts.

Answer (score 1):

A good intuitive way to see that $R \mid_Y$ is an equivalence relation is to convince yourself that a relation on $X$ is an equivalence relation if and only if it divides $X$ into distinct, non-empty regions. This is the essence of the idea behind equivalence relations and it's supposed to be very intuitive.

Therefore, if a relation divides $X$ into distinct non-empty regions, it will divide a non-empty subset of $X$ to distinct non-empty regions as well.

Moreover, your relation $R \mid_Y$ is nothing but the restriction of $R \subseteq X\times X$ to the elements in $Y \times Y$. If some property holds for every $(a,b) \in X \times X$ then surely it holds for every elment in $Y \times Y$ too because $Y \times Y \subseteq X \times X$.